# Using CellStyle when adding rows with BootstrapTable

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a Bootstrap-Table with a a button to add a new row of data. I would like to color the cell of a certain column (text2) for each new row as it's inserted. I am using the built in method `cellStyle()` as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/9/, but the function method never seems to be called.

Documentation for Bootstrap-Table:
http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

Table declaration with cellStyle parameter:

```
<table id="table" data-pagination="true"  data-cell-style="cellStyle" class="table table-striped"></table>
```

function to add style:

```
function cellStyle(value, row, index, field) {
  if (index === 0 && field == 'text2') {
    return {classes: 'warning'};
  }
  else {
    return {};
  }
}
```

My full code:

http://jsfiddle.net/wtg54xpy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something similar to this? http://jsfiddle.net/fp61qL0k/

The documentation says you should be adding the function to the table column header, not the table itself. From here it's just manipulating the function.

```
{
   field: 'text2',
   title: 'TEXT 2',
   cellStyle: cellStyle,
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did see the table header thing. The tricky part is I need it just on the new rows, not the whole column.

Comment: There are a few ways you can do that. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/85h32nyz/